# DNS unable to resolve but can ping and use nslookup using FQDN?

Tags: networking, dns, ping, iis, azure

First time posting a question so please let me know of any advice.

So I have IIS running on an Azure VM.

There is an internal DNS entry within my network which points to the IP address of the server, as it should. I ping and use NSLookup on the domain name and it responds as expected. I use the domain name on the server itself and it resolves to the website. I use the IP address in the browser of the remote computer and it also resolves to the website. However, when I try to use the domain name on an remote computer it states "Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) Your requested host could not be resolved by DNS." It seems like the dns was set up correctly. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting.

When I checked Fiddler it gave error 404. Does this mean that the issue is within IIS itself? Why does it say there's a problem with the DNS? Do I have to "allow" the VM to accept request coming from that domain name? Does binding have something to do with this (Although I did try to add the domain to the IIS Site Binding)?

Any suggestion would help as I've tried scouring the internet for days on a solution.

Edit: Also one thing I forgot to mention is that domain also works on the remote computer when I use RDP and as well as other programs such as FileMaker (This is for a FileMaker Server).

Thank you,

Your friendly neighborhood newbie

Comment: To clarify, if you open a browser on the server itself which is running IIS, and type in the domain name, the website comes up as expected? Is the address shown in the browser address bar still the expected domain?

Comment: @AK_oz Yes, exactly! That's why this is so frustrating and has me pulling my hair out. Also one thing I forgot to mention is that domain also works on the remote computer when I use RDP and as well as other programs such as FileMaker. Just not the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote computer is using a DNS that doesn't know your server IP address.  To resolve, you can register your domain with a domain registrar if you are using an internet DNS or add an entry to the DNS used by the client machine if it is a private DNS.

Alternatively, you can add an entry to the hosts file on the client machine which will resolve the issue on that client only.

Comment: I would say that would be the case however when I ping and use nslookup on the domain it resolves correctly. So if that was the case wouldn't ping and nslookup not work correctly when pinging the domain name?

Comment: @jayp what happens if you add a hosts file entry for the server?

Comment: I'm going to give that a try once I get back to my computer.

Comment: so when I edit the hosts file nothing happens at the browser level. It seems like it's a proxy issue. When I stop using the system proxy settings I am able to access the site via domain. I think I am on the right track now...

Comment: this put me on the right track. I was able to solve the issue. I wrote a script to see what the site returns when I use the domain. It returned what was expected. I then used FireFox and turned off the proxy settings. The site then resolved correctly. So it seems like it was a proxy issue that caused the FQDN to not resolve. I used another FQDN and now everything is up and running. Thanks!